# React native using a map function on an array to select items

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, map-function

I am having a little bit of an issue trying to solve this problem. Ok so I have a react native app that I am fetching data from my back end. I am using a Flatlist with a ListItem inside of it. I have my data displaying like this...

```
Bacon Burger
13.50
Fried Fish
10.50
Pizza
9.60
Turkey Burger
12.00
```

thru my flatlist/listitem. I have it set up where you have the item and underneath the item I have the item's price. I have set up a function that pairs the item and its price together. Here is that piece of code....

```
function pair(item, index) {
        const rows = category.reduce(function (rows, key, index) {
            return (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) 
            : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows;
        }, []);
}
```

What I am trying to do is when I click on an item, I want to be able to select the item (that I picked) and also its price (that goes with it) together. Once that item is picked I want to be able to take both the item and its price and set them to two different variables using useState. I know how to set them to their variables. I am just having a problem selecting and console.log my selection.

The steps that I took was to map over the array and the item that I selected, I would alert it to see if it works. Here is that code...

```
function pair(item, index) {
        const rows = category.reduce(function (rows, key, index) {
            return (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) 
            : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows;
        }, []);
        const food = rows.map((i) => {
            const price = i;
            return price;
        });
        alert(food);   
    }
```

When I do run this code, all it does it give me all of the items together in one long array. It does not alert the selected item that I pressed. I also tried to use const price = i.split(','); and it did not work. I know I am missing something. I just don't get how I can't just click on the item and just display that item and its price, instead of clicking on one item and everything in the array is alerted.

Here is my full where the items are rendered....

```js
 const {category, setCategory}= useContext(ItemContext);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const selectionMode = useSelectionChange(items);
    const [eats, setEats] = useState([]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [bill, setBill] = useState([]);


const pressItem = (item, index) => {
            pair(item);   
        };

        function pair(item, index) {
            const rows = category.reduce(function (rows, key, index) {
                return (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) 
                : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows;
            }, []);
            const food = rows.map((i) => {
                const price = i;
                return price;
            });
            alert(food);
        }

        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Icon 
                    name='arrow-left'
                    color="#000000"
                    size={25}
                    style={styles.menuIcon}
                    onPress={back}
                />
                
                <FlatList 
                    data={category}
                    //extraData={rows}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    rows
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <ListItem
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                        title={item}
                        onPress={() => pressItem(item)}
                        style={[item.selected ? styles.selected : styles.normal]}
                        bottomDivider
                        chevron
                        />
                    )}
                />
```

Comment: Is the `pair` method called onClick? What object is used to generate the flatlist?

Comment: I have another function that is called pressItem, and I have the function pair(item) being called in there when an item is pressed.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you render the item list? Ideally, you would not have to generate the pairs again on click.

Comment: sorry I just updated my question and added the full code. The reason I have pair(item) in pressItem is because pressItem does other things also. But the code I just posted is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Without calling `pair` from `pressItem` can't you just pass what you need from the `onPress` method?

Comment: Also, I'm to fully sure what category looks like.

Comment: sorry I just updated it again. And I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well maybe I didn't explain what I am looking to do correctly. I have pair set up how I need it where it pairing the items and prices that belong together. So now I just need to...let's say I clicked on Bacon Burger. I am trying to get it to alert just bacon burger and 13.50. Right now the way it set up the entire array is alerted. I just need for whatever item I click on that item and its price is alerted.

Comment: Is 13.50 already calculated? Is it displayed anywhere?

Comment: yes the 13.50 is an item that is being fetched from my backend. I also checked and it is considered a number.

Comment: I think it might be easier if you can create a CodeSandbox for this issue. Or you could post a sample value of `category`.